# Server-side script at Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

When you have a dropbox account, you get a public folder which essentially gives you **free HTML/Javascript webhosting**.

Does anyone know if there is some way to use server-side scripts such as **PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl** at dropbox?

Comment: It's better not to do that as this will evoke high traffic on your account and probably you'll be banned.

Answer (score 6):

No they don't support that, because it wasn't intent to be used as a web-hosting. It's more for easier share and for simple tests. If you for any reason will kinda abuse the Public folder then they will disable your Public folder for few days and they will notify you via e-mail.

Comment: thanks, it seems like dropbox could morph into an ISP with relatively little effort: add scripting and domain redirecting and they could compete directly with ISPs who charge for the same product, or they could charge for it, the ability to "upload" files without messing with FTP is a nice feature

Comment: @Edward nothing is really hard to implement.. the question is wether they want to mess with it or not.. and dont forget that this will generate addition (and unwanted) traffic to the already huge traffic to their service..